# Two phase commit transaction in Java EE 5

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, ejb, jta

I want to know that how can I do two phase commit transaction by using Java EE5...I am using EJB with JPA which has hibernate configured with MySql. I just want to use JAVA EE specification for transaction not using hibernate or JDBC specific object....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do, to ensure that JTA transactions are used to perform all transactional work in JPA, is to specify that the Persistence Unit type is JTA, and designate a JTA datasource for use by the JPA provider. Your persistence.xml file would have contents similar to the following:

```
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <!-- Specifies the type of the entity managers used by the persistence unit,
         as a JTA entity manager -->
    <persistence-unit name="example-pu" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <!-- Specifies a JTA datasource for use by the JPA provider.
             All connections obtained by the JPA provider for this persistence unit
             will be from this datasource -->
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/myDS</jta-data-source>
            ...
    </persistence-unit>
 </persistence>
```

Additionally, you must ensure that the datasource defined in the `jta-data-source` attribute, does not employ optimizations like allowing local transactions. In simpler words, all transactions involving the said datasource must be XA transactions, or the datasource must be an XA datasource without any support for local transactions.

Note that merely specifiying a JTA data source is not sufficient. You must define the persistence unit as one requiring the use of JTA entity managers, as an undefined value for the `transaction-type` attribute, depends on the environment in which the JPA provider operates. If the provider operates in a Java EE environment, `JTA` entity managers will be created, where as `RESOURCE_LOCAL` entity managers will be created in a Java SE environment.

Also, note that, if you specify the `transaction-type` as `RESOURCE_LOCAL`, then in a Java EE environment, the JPA provider will ignore the `jta-data-source` value, and will instead rely on the `non-jta-data-source` value for creating connections.

Comment: Thank you so much for you prompt reply....If u can show me how to do step by step configuration that will be really appreciable as I am newbie in this transaction world...

Comment: What do you mean by step by step configuration? It will almost certainly be different for each container. Also, I believe it would be served better by asking a different question, as its subject is different from the current one.

Comment: I am stuck in the configuration for giving XA data source for mysql for persistance.xml...

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence>
 <persistence-unit name="jpa">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>jpa.SampleData</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/bks_main"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>

Comment: I suppose you've already created a XA datasource then. In that case, just copy the relevant bits from the `persistence.xml` listed in my answer. You'll need to add the attribute `transaction-type="JTA"` to your persistence unit, and specify the JNDI name of the datasource in `<jta-data-source>jdbc/myDS</jta-data-source>`, substituting `jdbc/myDS` with the JNDI name of your datasource. You can do this with a text editor or from a GUI configuration utility (if one is available with your IDE).

Comment: <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <!--
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        -->
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit> 
</persistence>

Comment: And, one more thing - you can remove the `hibernate.connection.*` properties from your current `persistence.xml` file, as they are no longer required; you don't want them lying there to create troubles.

Comment: So how do I create JNDI source for the mysql database?

Comment: Which Java EE container are you using? The JNDI datasource creation steps vary from one container to another.

Comment: do i need to define it in JBOSS?

Comment: Yes. If you are finding trouble with creating one even after following the instructions in the JBoss guide, ask another question with the jboss tag. If this is specific to JBoss 5 - look into the [administration guide](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Administration_And_Configuration_Guide/5/html/Configuring_JDBC_DataSources.html). I couldn't find one for JBoss 6, so if you need one for that version, you should post a new question; apparently I haven't worked a lot with JBoss 6.